# How to verify a NativeScript ECDSA signature generated on Android phone with Java Security Library?

Tags: java, android, digital-signature, ecdsa

## Setup

I use an Android mobile phone with a NativeScript app to locally sign a hexadecimal message. I want to verify the signature remotely on a server, but it keeps failing.

My private key comes from a 24-word mnemonic, and the key was derived from the Secp256r1 Curve. (Not Secp256K1, but Secp256R1)

Android Phone:

- NativeScript with ported Java.security library
- Keystore in which I inserted the private key

I extracted the Public Key from the Keystore and verified with my mnemonic phase (from which I can get my private + public key) that the correct key is in the Keystore.

Remote Server:

- Java project
- Java.security library (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html)
- BouncyCastle as Provider

## Code

**Android Phone**

```
const sign = (keyStore: java.security.KeyStore, message: string, hash: string): void => {
    const Signature = java.security.Signature;
    const byteBuffer = stringToByteBuffer(message);
    const { key, pub } = getPrivateAndPublicKey(keyStore);
    const sig = Signature.getInstance('SHA256withECDSA');
    const signing = signByteBuffer(sig, key, byteBuffer);
    verifySignature(sig, pub, byteBuffer, signing, hash);
}
```

**Server code**

```
// Pubkey
String pubkey = "02bd78c6f7bd9314196392992283b16cb1848adb15cb5d04776da537c2d78b2097";
PublicKey publicKey = PublicKeyHelpers.getPublicKey(pubkey, HsmConstants.ParameterSpec.secp256r1);

// Payload
String payloadString = "ba06ae76b062f08a1b0a869d9d202d99d65c894bb6ba611df6259dca3d51472e";
byte[] payload = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(payloadString);

// Signature
String signatureString = "3046022100ca3cf346e3a9bc466630d70cb9ad30abdaaa9791db5bbb666c0bddfc56d981ca022100ed55a40b70aadf49384acb84f771de0923863d696b52c65917854034575e8457";
byte[] signature = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(sigString);

// VERIFY
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
Signature verifySignature = Signature.getInstance(SHA256withECDSA.toString(), BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
verifySignature.initVerify(publicKey);
verifySignature.update(payload);
boolean result = verifySignature.verify(signature);
```

## Problem Discussion

The Public Key is the one I got from my Android Phone Keystore.
The Signature was created on the Android Phone by signing the Payload.

I also built a TypeScript project with the `elliptic` library and `bip39` library. There I copy-pasted the exact same data, but there it also always fails the signature verification.

The Android Phone always verifies the signature as correct, the Java project and the TypeScript project always verify the signature as incorrect.

Then I studied this website on ECDSA signatures: https://cryptobook.nakov.com/digital-signatures/ecdsa-sign-verify-messages

The article states there are 2 ways to generate ECDSA signatures:

- Deterministic (k-value is HMAC-derived from private key + hash(message)
- Random (k-value is randomly taken between 1 to n-1)

Funny thing is, if I use DETERMINISTIC signing on the Android Phone (so I DON'T use the Keystore, but just the mnemonic to sign), then everything works as intended: I can sign on Android Phone, produce a DER signature and verify it in the Java and TypeScript projects. I know it's deterministic because signing the same msg always returns the same signature.

The KeyStore on the other hand generates a random k-value, as the signature is always different for the same msg.

## Ideas?

What could be going wrong? Maybe the `Signature.Instance` algorithm should be `NONEWithECDSA` instead of `SHA256WithECDSA`, or something else?
Does the Android Keystore produce Signatures with a different format or algorithm or something I'm not aware of?

Comment: Please reduce your post to a *single* unambiguously answerable question.

Comment: @possum Hiya, I reworded the title to a more specific question. I think the extensive info I typed could be helpful in finding a solution to this problem.